# How to use the components in Sitecore/Keystone MVC?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am very new to Sitecore and i am confused between the Sitecore and Keystone component i.e. what is the difference between them and how to use it in the website we build in Sitecore. Please help me to solve this confusion?

I have created a website using Sitecore MVC and i am facing issue in using the existing components such as Breadcrumb, Sitemap in the created website. So will you please explain me how to include Sitecore /Keystone components (example such as Breadcrumb, Sitemap, Search, ..) is Sitecore web application, please provide an example?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Keystone is a 3rd party addition to Sitecore. It contains a set of Sitecore components. You can add your own components to Sitecore as well.

Here is [Keystone Manual - Installation & Developer Guid](http://www.keystoneforsitecore.com/download.aspx?f=pdf&key=0adda031-13cb-48fe-b372-1f3806504246) which should give you nice introduction to Keystone.